# Photo memories created in a different language

Tags: iphone, photos, internationalization, language

I'm using Apple Cloud photo library. From time to time new photo memory is created and shared with me on my iPhone photo widget (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207023 to see exact feature I'm talking about). Love the feature, have been using and enjoying it for several years. Nothing changed in my iPhone settings recently, but all of a sudden I see new memories are being created using non-English (Russian if it matters) language. I do have multiple languages configured on my iPhone (English being primary, then Spanish, Russian, French, Ukrainian etc) - but this has been setup like this forever and nothing changed recently.

When I say language of photo memory I mean title of a photo slideshow. For example it was "This day in 2014", and now it would create "В этот день 2009". Old memories didn't change - I can still see English language title, but new ones are being created in Russian.

How is it controlled and how do I put it back?